# Reading a word document (text and images) and Pasting to other word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office

I have a word document which has both text and images. When I'm reading this document and writing back the content to an other document, Images are missing.
How can i also copy the images as well?

Example: Word document has

[image: Word Document has following data]

After wring the content to other document, output is coming as

[image]

Code Sample:

```
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object filename = "C:\\SampleInput.docx";
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass AC = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
        object readOnly = false;
        object isVisible = true;
        doc = AC.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible, ref isVisible, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        string inputText = doc.Content.Text;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application winword = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        winword.ShowAnimation = false;
        winword.Visible = false;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = winword.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        document.Content.SetRange(0, 0);
        document.Content.Text = inputText;

        object outputPath = @"c:\FormattedOutput.docx";
        document.SaveAs2(ref outputPath);
        document.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        document = null;
        winword.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        winword = null;
```

Comment: I agree with RIch's suggestion. But your code is faulty. Do *not* use the constructs for `AC` and `doc`; do *not* instantiate as `Application.Class` and do *not* use `=new Word.Document` in the declaration of a Word document. These can cause all kinds of weird problems at some point. Use instead the constructs as for `winword` and `document`. Note that you do *not* need to instances of the `Word.Application` for two documents. Start one instance and use it for both documents.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Range.FormattedText property. In other words, with the source and destination documents open and the ranges established the commands would look like this ...

```
DestinationRange.FormattedText = SourceRange.FormattedText;
```

Your current code is only picking up plain text and storing it in a string variable. The string variable cannot hold image objects.